# How to use PHP and JAVA in thrift

Tags: java, php, ubuntu-12.04, thrift

I have installed thrift 0.8.0 in Ubuntu 12.04
I followed the all commands correctly with out any error but after installation it's working perfect

**Now i want to use PHP by using thrift but in below code it only Shows YES for C++ and Python i need java and PHP but that two languages shows NO How can i use PHP and java in thrift, is there any library for java and php ?**

```
thrift 0.8.0

Building code generators ..... :

Building C++ Library ......... : yes
Building C (GLib) Library .... : no
Building Java Library ........ : no
Building C# Library .......... : no
Building Python Library ...... : yes
Building Ruby Library ........ : no
Building Haskell Library ..... : no
Building Perl Library ........ : no
Building PHP Library ......... : no
Building Erlang Library ...... : no
Building Go Library .......... : no

Building TZlibTransport ...... : yes
Building TNonblockingServer .. : yes

Using Python ................. : /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: The `configure` script checks for the presence of all (most) target languages. If a particular language is detected, then it is automatically enabled (unless you specify one of those `--without-xxx` switches, of course). So my guess would be that you either lack these on your machine or the script was not able to detect them. BTW, the current version is 0.9.1, and the 0.9.2 release is planned.

Answer (score 2):

First, download the source version of Thrift.  I would strongly recommend using a newer version if possible.  There are several ways to include the Thrift Java library (may have to change slightly for your Thrift version):

If you are using maven, you can add the maven coordinates to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
    <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Alternatively you can just download the JAR and add it your project:

http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/thrift/libthrift/0.9.1/libthrift-0.9.1.jar

If you are using a version that has not been published to the central maven repositories, you can download the source tarball and navigate to the lib/java directory and build it with Apache Ant by typing:

```
ant
```

The library JAR will be in the lib/java/build directory. Optionally you can add the freshly built JAR to your local Maven repository:

```
mvn install:install-file -DartifactId=libthrift -DgroupId=org.apache.thrift -Dvers
```

For the PHP library, navigate to the `lib/php/src` directory and copy the PHP files into your project.  You can then use the Thrift\ClassLoader\ThriftClassLoader class or the autoload.php script to include the Thrift PHP library.  No build necessary unless you are trying to use the native PHP extension that implements the thrift protocol.

Answer (score 0):

- for Java: you can download .jar library, javadoc here http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/thrift/libthrift/0.9.1/
- for PHP: copy [thrift-source]/lib/php/lib to your project and use it. This is a example to use:  https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/php

P/s: i want to use .dll PHP extension rather than PHP source files. Anyone care it, we can discuss at here [How can write or find a PHP extension for Apache Thrift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623610/how-can-write-or-find-a-php-extension-for-apache-thrift)