# How can write or find a PHP extension for Apache Thrift

Tags: php, c++, apache, thrift

Apache Thrift now only support PHP source files (copy **[thrift-source]/lib/php/lib** to own project to use). But, Can i find a **.dll PHP extension file** instead that? Where can i find it?

Otherwise, i have to write it. Could you tell me how to do that (i usually use Apache server)?

Is that right if I install C++ Lib of Apache Thrift and write PHP extension base on it? Or, can i generate from thrift-source (i have looked cpp files  **[thrift-source]/lib/php/src/ext**, but maybe protocol only)?

Comment: I only want to know if it exist (maybe, i can save my time), otherwise, i will write it myself and contribute this helpful open source.